# Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Crm, Version=5.0.0.0

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, microsoft-dynamics

I have installed Dynamics CRM 2011 and I have configured it for claims based authentication and internet facing deployment.

After browsing to it, I am getting the following error:

```
Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Crm, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
```

How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 1):

Do you have the SDK assemblies in the GAC and does the service account running CRM have access rights?